# Is $\mathrm{EllipticPi}(n,\varphi, m)$ periodic for $n>1?$

Tags: functions, special-functions

The Wolfram function site lists the [quasi-periodicity relation](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticPi3/04/02/03/) for the incomplete elliptic integral **EllipticPi** restricted to $-1\le n\le 1$
although actually it seems to work for $n<-1$ and $n \sin^2 \varphi < 1$ as well.
$$\Pi(n,\varphi+k\pi,m)=2k\,\Pi(n,m) + \Pi(n,\varphi,m), \quad k \in \mathbb{Z},\; -1\le n \le 1$$
I could not find any Mathematica documention for a relation when $n \sin^2 \varphi > 1;$ and the values from other CAS differ from Mathematica

```
Pi(n,phi,m) for n=2, phi=1+k*pi, m=1/2
Mathematica (10.3.1 Linux/ARM)
   k=0    0.704583746768798 - 1.813799364234218 I
   k=8    0.704583746768798 - 1.813799364234218 I
   k=-4   0.704583746768798 - 1.813799364234218 I
MPMath
   k=0    0.704583746768798  -  1.813799364234217 I
   k=8   -4.312131188674144  - 30.834589191981706 I
   k=-4   3.212941214490268  + 12.696595549639525 I
Maxima
   k=0    0.704583746768798
   k=8   -4.312131188674136
   k=-4   3.212941214490266
```

So actually the Mathematica results seems to be **periodic** for $n> 1.$

> Is this periodicity a bug or a documented feature?

**Edit:** Here the exported Mathematica text

```
In[1]:= N[EllipticPi[2,1, 1/2],15]
Out[1]= 0.70458374676880-1.81379936423422 I
In[2]:= N[EllipticPi[2,1+8*Pi, 1/2],15]
Out[2]= 0.70458374676880-1.81379936423422 I
In[3]:= N[EllipticPi[2,1-4*Pi, 1/2],15]
Out[3]= 0.70458374676880-1.81379936423422 I
```

Comment: It's not a bug.For `n>1` integral of EllipicPi converages only if ``fi < ArcSin[1/Sqrt[n]]``.See `62:12:3` on page `661` in the book https://books.google.pl/books?id=lITvjwEACAAJ&hl=pl&source=gbs_book_other_versions

Comment: @mariusz-iwaniuk: IMO 62:12:3 lists the range restriction for their program  Equator but says nothing about periodicity.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17182/periodicity-of-ellipticpi to this end. The question is not related to Mathematica, but to math.

Comment: @user64494: No this **is** related to Mathematica (obviously because either it is
a bug or feature). IMO the 'answers' in Math.StackExchange do not apply:
The accepted answer ignores the fact, that the two integrals at Wikipedia are 
the same only if $|\varphi| \le \pi/2$ (and cannot explain the quasi-periodicity for $n<1$).
The second 'answer' declares itself as a comment and is restricted to
$0<m<1.$ And if it were correct, it would show that $\Pi(n,\varphi,m)$ is
**not periodic** because $F(\varphi, m)$ is without doubt **quasi-periodic**.

Comment: The Maple command MmaTranslator:-FromMma("EllipticPi[a,z, b]")  outputs EllipticPi(sin(z), a, sqrt(b)). There is no restrictions on the parameters a and b in Maple. These two statements implies the periodicity of EllipticPi in Maple. It should be noticed that the values of EllipticPi[a,z, b] in Mathematica and EllipticPi(sin(z), a, sqrt(b)) in Maple differ. I find nothing about the periodicity under consideration in Abramowitz&Stegun.

Comment: Here Maple V and Maple 7 give for the k=8 case
`16*EllipticPi(2,1/2*sqrt(2))+EllipticPi(sin(1),2,1/2*sqrt(2))`,
this is the quasi-periodic property. Evaluated the result is
-4.31213118867421, ie the same as Maxima.
I know that newer Maple versions might differ,
see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720709/

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you used in Mathematica?  Obviously with exact values of `n`, `ϕ`, and `m`, Mathematica will not return a machine precision number.  I am having trouble reproducing your shown results.

Comment: @chuy: See edit

Comment: This is more of a math question than a *Mathematica* question, I would say. Have you seen the formulae that convert the characteristic $n$ for $\Pi$? Those reduce your principal value circular case to the circular case where your previous quasiperiodicity formula applies.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay: Good to see you again. Meanwhile I have implemented a optional Mathematica mode for my library, where I used the formula shown in the edit/update of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720709/ (is this the transformation you talk about?). It seems that it is also a question whether a Cauchy principal value or an analytic continuation should be used (which would be an implentation detail, and as shown different program give different results).

Comment: Interesting, this is a little related to stuff I should be hopefully releasing in the next few weeks. I don't have Abramowitz and Stegun with me at the moment, but I'll try to think about it (and maybe even post an answer at math.SE).